# Make ng-change wait for $watch to be done

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a field with `ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="themodel"`
and a `$watch(themodel, function = {longAsyncFunc();})`

I'd like myFunc() to be triggered only when the longAsyncFunc has returned.
I though about doing something like :

`$watch(themodel, function = {longAsyncFunc(); $scope.ready = true;})`

```
myFunc = function() {
    while(!$scope.ready) {
        ;
    }
    $scope.ready = false;
    //do stuff
    }
```

But it ends up on a infinite loop, and the watch is never triggered.

I know I should use promise but the longAsyncFunc already catch the .then() of the async call and I'd rather not modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback like this:

```
$scope.longAsyncFunc = function(callback) {
   //do what ever you want
   callback();
}

$scope.$watch(themodel, function {
  longAsyncFunc(myFunc); 
  $scope.ready = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using `$watch` & `ng-change` together, I'd suggest you to use ng-change directive rather than `$watch`, `longAsyncFunc` will return promise object.

**HTML**

`ng-change="changeFunction()"`

**Controller**

```
$scope.changeFunction = function() {
    longAsyncFunc().then(function(data){
        //this will ensure the async load completed.
        myFunction();
    })
}
```